# Is an fscanf/scanf/sscanf conversion specification with assignment suppressed not a conversion?

Tags: c, language-lawyer

What should `sscanf("x", "%*c%c", &(char){0})` return?

The libraries that Apple and [Godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/WTcfo5vWM) are using return −1, which is their `EOF`. However, C 2018 7.21.6.7 3 tells us `sscanf` returns “`EOF` if an input failure occurs before the first conversion (if any) has completed.” `%*c` is a conversion specification with assignment suppressed. It completes, and then input failure (end of string) occurs before the `%c` completes. Then `sscanf` should return “the number of input items assigned,” which is zero.

Is there any text in the standard that would tell us `%*c` is to be regarded as not a conversion?

Comment: IMO conversion happens when the scanned value is assigned to the parameter of the `scanf`. Otherwise is just a part of the format string

Comment: Seems like a simple typo in the spec: "first conversion" should be "first assignment" since the return value is only concerned with the number of assignments.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apparently C99 §7.19.6.2 point 15 (and C17 §7.21.6.2 point 15) tells us that:

> Trailing white space (including new-line characters) is left unread unless matched by a
> directive. **The success of literal matches and suppressed assignments is not directly
> determinable other than via the `%n` directive.**

Where "suppressed assignments" is defined as `%*` followed by a specifier.

So what you see in your example seems in accordance with the standard: you cannot deduce whether `%*c` was matched or not, unless you use a `n` specifier to count the number of scanned characters.

Additionally, [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68656580/is-an-fscanf-scanf-sscanf-conversion-specification-with-assignment-suppressed-no#comment121334927_68656580) by [user3386109](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3386109/user3386109) notes that "the return value is only concerned with the number of assignments" and the C standard text quoted in the question might be intended to say "first assignment" rather than "first conversion".

Comment: So if you need to know if the character was read and suppressed, you would have to do `sscanf("x","%n%*c%n%c",&n1,&n2,&chr)`, then test if `n1 != n2`. Note that your use of `&(char){0}` is likely to cause an error, since it attempts to write into a read-only segment.

Comment: @SGeorgiades you just need one `%n` after the `%*c` plus check if the value in the output parameter is 1.

Comment: @SGeorgiades not really, Compound Literals in function scope are lvalues with automatic storage duration - `C11`, chapter [§6.5.2.5p5](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.5.2.5p5). It is okay to write to it.

Comment: Marco Bonelli, Concerning "plus check if the value in the output parameter is 1", with `int n = 0; sscanf("x","%*c%n.....",&n, ....)`, it is sufficient to test if `n != 0` to conclude that a suppressed assignment occurred.  Return value of `sscanf()` is not needed.